# multiple count and use subsctract function in one query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I try to do more advance query in mysql but got error in query, i try to count and group by. here is my query:

```
"select department,
(select count(id) from mcu group by dept) as tot1,
(select count(status_mcu) from mcu where status_mcu='done' group by dept) as tot2,
(tot1 - sum(select count(status_mcu) where status_mcu='done') as tot3,
FROM mcu"
```

can you help me out ? what wrong with my query ? i do some search in other threads and this is what i got. try do query like :

```
"select department,
select count(id),
sum(case when status_mcu='done' then 1 end)
...
"
```

not worked too. Any help is appreciate.

---

> my sql version is 5.5.25 – casthrotopes

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! What version of MySQL are you using - should be in **every** question! Also, please provide  a fiddle with your tables and data and also your desired result.

Comment: thanks for fast response @Vérace, my sql version is 5.5.25

Comment: My first question might be "why are you running an antique?" - but I know that programmers/DBAs don't always have control over their environments - now, what about your tables and data and desired resutl?

Comment: *here is my query* It is logically wrong (the subquery will most likely return a rowset, not a scalar value). And it is synthactically wrong (nested aggregate functions, lost data source). Post the task itself, not only the attempt to solve it.

Comment: When responding to a request for more information about a question, please put that information into the text of the **question itself** - you can let the person who requested it know by putting a comment below theirs and putting `@` + their handle into the body of your response - e.g. for me it would be `@Vérace`.

Comment: Unbalanced parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the exact error message returned, I can't be 100% certain, but there are two glaring errors:

1. Is the column name `Department` or `Dept`?  This does not seem clear.
2. You cannot reference `tot1` unless it is first derived in a CTE or sub-select (derived table).
3. The subquery `sum(select count(status_mcu) where status_mcu='done')` does not have a `FROM` clause.  Furthermore, I'm not sure what purpose where aggregating a high-level aggregate is necessary/desired.
4. As a general critique, you're hitting the same table over and over again which is not optimal from a performance standpoint.

Start with this and see if it returns the desired results (if it doesn't, you'll need to clarify your question to provide the proper logic):

```
SELECT
  mcu.Dept
 ,COUNT(mcu.Id) AS Tot1
 ,SUM
    (
      CASE
        WHEN mcu.status_mcu='done' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END
    ) AS tot2
 ,COUNT(mcu.Id) - 
    SUM
      (
        CASE
          WHEN mcu.status_mcu='done' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END
      ) AS tot3
FROM
  mcu mcu
GROUP BY
  mcu.Dept
```

Comment: Thankyou your query work like magic! it work now.